# Web scraping from the list of urls with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some listings property websites from the list. I wrote simple code to get data from one url, but when I'm trying with list ['url1','url2'] I have nothing as the result. I was trying also with csv list, but I still have nothing. I checked a lot of similar topics, but still empty result. Could you help me please to understand how to do it?

'''

```
import lxml
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/105-Itasca-St-Boston-MA-02126/59137872_zpid/'
response = requests.get(url)
req_headers = {
    'accept': 
    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
    Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
url 
r = s.get(url, headers=req_headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'ds-value'}).text
property_type = soup.find('span', {'class': 'ds-home-fact-value'}).text
address = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'ds-address-container'}).text

price, property_type, address '''
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish what you're asking to do with multiple urls, all you need to do is put them in a list and iterate over it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/105-Itasca-St-Boston-MA-02126/59137872_zpid/',
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

        # do something with soup
```

**However**, the main issue here is that pretty much everything interesting on your example webpage seems to be generated by JavaScript. For example, if you:

```
print(soup.body)
```

You'll see the body of html for this webpage has next to nothing (no price, no house details, etc.), save for a captcha mechanism to verify you're a human. You'll need to find a way to wait for the JavaScript to be rendered on the page to be able to scrape the details. Look into the python module *selenium* as a potential workaround for accomplishing this.